# Why does my REGEX for website validation not work?

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule, regular-expressions

I have the expression working correctly here:
http://regexr.com/3gemo

I tried converting it to a validation rule in Salesforce but the **following doesn't even save and keeps throwing a 'Syntax error**'[image]:

```
AND(  
    NOT(ISBLANK(Website)),
    NOT(REGEX(Website,'^https:\/\/)?([A-Za-z0-9]\.|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9]\.){1,3}[A-Za-z]{2,6}'))  
)
```

Expected behavior:

- A label may contain 2 to 63 characters [ Both on the left and right side of (.) ]
- The characters allowed in their labels are a subset of the ASCII character set, consisting of characters a through z, A through Z, digits 0 through 9, and hyphen 
     -- Cannot use characters with accent marks 
     -- Cannot use symbols except dash
     -- Cannot use ^ anywhere
- Labels may not start or end with a hyphen

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to escape a character, you need to use two backslash characters (`\\`) rather than one (`\`). Also, I do not believe you need to escape forward slash (`/`) characters in this context.

Requisite changes:

```
AND( 
    NOT(ISBLANK(Website)), 
    NOT(REGEX(Website,'^(https://)?([A-Za-z0-9]\\.|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9]\\.){1,3}[A-Za-z]{2,6}')) 
)
```

Comment: Adrian, I thought I had the REGEX nailed down but it doesn't satisfy certain criteria (mistake on my part). Do you recommend posting a new question or should I continue the thread here?

Comment: New question. Your key issue here was how to get the rule itself to save.